# Go Get Not Downloading to SRC Folder

Tags: go

Expected: I install the package using go get, and it creates all necessary folders in the src folder, but they only appear in the pkg/mod folder and I can’t use them.

Reality: it says it’s downloading, finishes, then nothing.

Everything is setup correctly in Windows Env Variables, this just.. doesn’t work.

Command Used: `go get github.com/fatih/color`

Go Env:

````
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\admin\Desktop\gostuff\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\admin\Desktop\gostuff
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=c:\go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=c:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.16
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=NUL
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build639062626=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches  ```
````

Comment: Go modules do not use or download anything into `$GOPATH/src`

Comment: All the videos I’ve seen showcase this as being the case, granted they aren’t recent; but I don’t understand why I can’t use the thing I’m installing then.

Comment: Your resources are out of date. Start with official documentation, like [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code), [Getting Started](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started), [Modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules), [Go Modules Reference](https://golang.org/ref/mod), etc.

Comment: I'm also seeing this in my mac, used this command in Windows was working fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go modules will hold the dependencies in $GOPATH/mod.

As such, when you'll import them into your project, you need to worry about two things: they are imported in a .go file and they are present in the go.mod file.

Once downloaded for a certain version, they will be available for all future projects.

If you want learn more about them and how they are organized, you can read the Go Modules Wiki available here https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Comment: Since (at least) 1.15, the location of the cache has moved to GOPATH[0]/pkg/mod as per https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#go-115

Answer (score 56):

Setting up `GO111MODULE` env variable to `off` solved it for me.
I'm using `zsh`. Here's the command I have put in my `.zshrc` file,

```sh
export GO111MODULE=off
```

My working environment: `macOS Big Sur`, `Go version: 1.16`

Comment: what exactly it means?

Comment: this saved my life

Comment: GO111MODULE=off forces Go to behave the GOPATH way, even outside of GOPATH. This will clone the module git repo to GOPATH.

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 20.4 too. Thanks you saved my day. I wonder why these settings were not in place by default when I installed go.

Comment: This worked, but I think there might be a better way.  i used this to 'go get' a package, but the package uses go modules, so had to remove the export.

Comment: This will disable Go modules and I think in >2021 year this is BAD!
If you just need to download the sources, and don't want to disable this, you can do: `GO111MODULE=off go get github.com/fatih/color`

Comment: Using this method will download the sources of all dependencies. This is probably not what people want. Using `git clone` is more a robust and "always works" way.

Answer (score 21):

Since Go 1.15, `go get` by default will download source codes inside `$GOPATH/pkg/mod/` (`GOMODCACHE`) which is in place of what it used to be `$GOPATH/src/`. (Ref: https://go.dev/doc/go1.15#go-command)

Turning off Go modules like `GO111MODULE=off` to download sources is a bad idea.

If you just need to download the sources, I strongly recommend you to use `git clone` instead.

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/fatih/color
```

If you need to have it in `$GOPATH/src/`, just run:

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/fatih/color $GOPATH/src/github.com/fatih/color
```

Please note that as of Go 1.14, Go projects are no longer confined to `$GOPATH/src/` with support of Go modules. You don't really need that folder now.
The `$GOPATH/src/` folder was for dependency management before even Go modules were introduced.

Users are now advised to move to Go modules as https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules states:
"Since Go 1.14, module support is considered ready for production use, and all users are encouraged to migrate to modules from other dependency management systems".

Answer (score 5):

You can try this command.

```
export GO111MODULE=off
go get github.com/fatih/color
```

Comment: Please try to add reason for why user should try the command , technical detail will be helpful

Comment: You would use this command if you want the source to just download into $GOPATH/src like it used to work for years until just somewhat recently.

Comment: it's ridiculous, but it works for go 1.17

Comment: Go 1.16 and 1.17 does not download source code to your GOPATH (go install command actually does not need GOPATH) when go modules is on. You can download github.com code to `src` directory by `go get` if you set it off and have GOPATH